# converting QBitArray to QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

This function doesnt work correctly for some inputs, So What is the mistake ?

All Projects Codes here : [link](http://www.kodhatasi.com/soru/366/qbitarray-ve-qbytearray-arasi-cevirmeler)

ps: I am using input that "bits.size()%8" equal to zero

```
QByteArray bitsToBytes(QBitArray bits) {
  QByteArray bytes;
  bytes.resize(bits.count()/8);

  // Convert from QBitArray to QByteArray
  for(int b=0; b<bits.count(); ++b)
    bytes[b/8] = ( bytes.at(b/8) | ((bits[b]?1:0)<<(b%8)));

  return bytes;
}
```

Comment: First, what do you want to get? Can you provide us sample input and output? Then, it seems your code is almost correct. An only advise: do not forget initialize variables before you use them, like this: `bytes.fill(0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topro algorithm should be correct as a whole. But my concert is with the test `bits[b]?1:0`.

By default, `operator[] ( int i )` return "the bit at index position i as a modifiable reference" while `operator[] ( int i ) const` return a boolean. If the first definition is chozen, you will test if a reference is true.

Try Topro algorithm with `bits.testBit(b)`.

Answer (score 1):

i think it's maybe the bits shall be left shifted `(7 - (b % 8))` bits

I tried this and got the expected result.

```
QBitArray bits;
QByteArray bytes;

bits.resize(12);
bits.fill(true);

bits.setBit(2,false);

bytes.resize((bits.count() - 1) / 8 + 1);

for(int b=0; b<bits.count(); ++b)
    bytes[b/8] = ( bytes.at(b/8) | ((bits[b]?1:0)<<(7-(b%8))));

for (int b=0;b<bytes.size();b++)
    printf("%d\n",(quint8)bytes.at(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case, where (bits.count() % 8) != 0 , e.g. 9
Then `bytes.resize(bits.count()/8);` returns the wrong result.

As Topro suggested in a comment, you could use `bytes.resize((bits.count() - 1) / 8 + 1))`.

Comment: @Topro: He is making a bitwise OR ; the order in which the bits are set should not matter

Comment: Yes, consider to be ```((bits.count() - 1) / 8 + 1)```

Comment: actually my problem is in the all data. Not only last byte